EF Core return from IAsyncEnumerable from FromSqlRaw mapping error
I have a query that is constructed like this to be able to add jsonb search expression and Ulid filter. With bare LINQ query is worked, but neither can be added with LINQ.
db.TryGetSchemaAndTableName<AssetMasterData>(out var schema, out var tableName);

var queryString =
    search.IsSet()
    ? $$"""
        SELECT * FROM {{schema}}."{{tableName}}"
            WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM jsonb_each_text("DisplayText") AS kv
            WHERE kv.value ILIKE @searchString
            )
        """
    :   $@"SELECT * FROM {schema}.""{tableName}"" WHERE 1=1"
    ;

List<object> parameters = new();

if (from.HasValue)
{
    queryString += " AND \"Id\" > @from";
    parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("from", from.Value));
}

if(search.IsSet())
{
    parameters.Add(new Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter("searchString", $"%{search}%"));
}

var res = db.AssetMasterDataInstances.FromSqlRaw(queryString, parameters)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsAsyncEnumerable()
        .WithCancellation(token);

await foreach (AssetMasterData item in res) <<< EXCEPTION
{
    yield return item;

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;
}

The exception is thrown at the marked position even if the query is the simplest one:

System.InvalidOperationException: The current provider doesn't have a
store type mapping for properties of type 'List<object>'.

Of course, the model of the returned items matches the model from which the query is executed:
public DbSet<AssetMasterData> AssetMasterDataInstances { get; set; }

Again: if I remove FromSqlRaw(... and apply any other filtering with LINQ, it works.
[Update]
My bad: "params fallacy". That list is a collection, but not an array, hence it is passed as a single element to the parameters params parameter. A .ToArray() saves the day...

It's always good to find a fix for the problem by ourselves (^_^)
